# How to add <i> inside input element using twitter-bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want the icon to show up inside the input, pushed to the right.  Here's what I have:

```
    <div id="side-menu" class="sidebar-nav span2">
        <div class="row-fluid" id="search-container">
            <div class="span1"></div>
            <div class="span10"><span><input class="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search"><i id="side-search-icon"class="icon-search"></i></span></div>
            <div class="span1"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/52/

Comment: I think in this case, it would be more easy to use an image instead of font awesome icon

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't have anything to do with the type of icon he uses. Just a little CSS magic and it'll be good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot place an element directly inside the input element (as @Ray Toal said), but you can manipulate the CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/P4qQx/2/

```
#side-search-icon{ margin-left: -25px; }
```

```
<div id="side-menu" class="sidebar-nav span2">
    <div class="row-fluid" id="search-container">
        <div class="span1"></div>
        <div class="span10">
            <input class="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
            <span id="side-search-icon"class="icon-search"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="span1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see the icon in the input in your fiddle :/

Comment: I forked it... try the link again and see if it made a difference, also, if you're in chrome, try the dev tools and see if there's a resource error.

Comment: Looks like it works if I shrink the width of my window - if it's too wide, the icon jumps down to the next line.  Thanks for your help by the way

Comment: Ah yes, you will have to manipulate some other CSS to add some fixed width goodness to prevent the wrap.

Comment: Doesn't that defeat the purpose of the fluid layout though?

Comment: just wrap the input with the width you want... you probably won't want it liquid anyways. `#search-container`